# When I switch the array of tabBarItems in iOS6, why do I get a blank screen?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, ios6, uiwindow

My App was working just great in 4.3 and 5.1. What I do is have a login view as the single view in a UITabBarController, and when the user logs in, my app changes the tabBarItems to a different set of viewControllers (many tabs). It was working just perfectly in iOS5, but now, its totally broken in iOS6 - what do I do.

Answer (score 2):

I spent hours and hours on this and finally found the problem. It seems that just switching out the tabBar array does not cause the viewControllers to go through the same initialization that they normally do. The solution was to first nil the rootViewController, then set it again. Once I did that all worked perfectly:

```
tabBarController.viewControllers = vcs; // my array, either a login view or the real array
tabBarController.customizableViewControllers = nil;
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
window.rootViewController = nil; // THIS WAS THE MAGIC LINE - nil then set again
window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I truly hope this saves someone else the hours of hair pulling I just went through!